# Migrating Oracle 9i database to MySql database on a different Windows Server

Tags: mysql, oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I need to migrate my Oracle 9i database with all its tables from windows server 2003 to MySql on another Windows Server 2012. The oracle database is connected to Visual Studio web project. I have successfully imported the files (.aspx) to Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Community edition.

(**Mind that I need to keep original database intact for few weeks of testing peroid, simply the migration should be , creating a clone copy and not moving the database.**)

I am facing problems as the visual studio project has code for connection with old oracle database. I need to recreate the functioning website.

The only thing remaining is migrating that old database to new server.
I tried [SQLWays](http://www.ispirer.com/products/why-sqlways) .  ***But It does that on single machine not from another server.***

**Please suggest solutions for migration between different servers.**

Further, what needs to be changed in my vb code even if I migrated the database successfully to get it working with visual studio 2013 project.
(***or may I ask a different question for that?***)

Comment: just change the connection string in the web config to point to the new database in your project.  ensure that visual studio and the new server have the dll's to connect to mysql

Comment: it would help if you told us how the vb application accesses the Oracle date...prepared SQL statement, stored procedures, ORM tool??

Comment: It uses :  
Me.OleDbSelectCommand#.Connection = Me.OleDbConnection1 in the vb code

Comment: @kevinsky something like prepared SQL statement : 
`Me.OleDbDeleteCommand1.CommandText = "DELETE FROM DISEASE WHERE (DIS_IDS = ?) AND (DIS_FNAME = ? OR ? IS NULL AND DIS_FNAM".......`

Answer (score 1):

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479500/migrate-from-oracle-to-mysql) on Stack Overflow indicates there is no built in functionality to do what you want but there are alternatives:

- export your tables to csv files and then import into MySql using LOAD DATA INFILE. This solution does not scale well for large databases or schemas with clobs and blobs that are images or documents.  SQL Developer can help you recreate your schema in MySql.
- roll your own solution with VB reading the data from Oracle and writing to MySql.  This takes time to code and test and is all throwaway code.
- Commercial products:  Golden Gate works great but will cost you far more than you expect

The data access code in your application should, in general, work without change but details are everything. Consult the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#BABHHAJC) for a comparison and you can see many differences and possible issues depending on what your schema has.